# window.parent.xxx.print() doesnt work if the content data is base64

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, iframe

I do have an `iframe` in which I dynamically generate a base64 data pdf file:

```
$("#pdfDocument").attr('src', "data:application/pdf;base64,"+base64data);
```

There are a button on the form and after the click it should call the default `print` behavior of the browser:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.parent.pdfDocument.print();" style="width:13em;margin-right:10px;"  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" >$i18n.getString( "btn_form_print" )</button>
```

The `pdfDocument` here is the name of the iframe:

```
<iframe style="border: 0 none" src="" id="pdfDocument" name="pdfDocument" width="100%" height="550" type='application/pdf'> </iframe>
```

When I click at this button I get the following error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

However, when I put directly the `pdf` file as a source inside the iframe, it works just fine. It gives an error only if I input the pdf file as base64 data.

Any ideas or directions are welcome.

Comment: well, cross origin is cross origin, and not much you can do to circumvent such security measures

Comment: @JaromandaX, googling also didnt help much. Any ideas of how else I could achieve it? I have to be able to print that base64 pdf file

Comment: Have you looked into Mozilla's PDF.js You'll need to rewrite your code a bit but it'll be worth it

Comment: @JaromandaX, ive been actually thinking about it. But adding 2.5mb lib to the web application which should work on slow DSL connection is hurting

Comment: 1MB of that is a demo pdf - but I feel your pain